# Error messages when extracting a .tar.bz2 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

While extracting a `.tar.bz2` file using the command

```
tar xjf git.tar.bz2
```

I received error messages that shows

> Cannot hard link to

and

> Cannot create symlink to

What will be the reason for those error messages and how to extract the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because the `tar` was created without the `--hard-dereference` and `--dereference` flags. Basically, the `tar` contains files that are hard and soft links to different places but they're not included in the tar file, so it will fail.

You'll have to create the `tar` file again with one or both the options I mentioned.

- More info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_71.html).

Comment: i got the tar file from some other source, is there any other possibilities for rectifying this error??

Comment: You might try with the `--ignore-command-error` flag, but I'm not sure it will work in this case. In any case, keep in mind that even if it worked, you'll have an incomplete file extraction since the tar file wasn't created correctly because both soft and hard links weren't included in the file.

Comment: is there any other method for extracting .taz.bz2 file ?? whether changing the method can rectify the error or it will be the case for all the possible methods??

Comment: I'm afraid there's not, since the problem happened at creation time, as the user should be aware that there are soft and hard links and include them in the package, but they didn't, so it's likely there will be missing files (or not, if the soft or hard links point to files that are also included in the .tar.bz2 file). But it's not up to you to solve the issue itself.

Comment: "Cannot hard link to `git/u-boot/arch/arm/include/asm/arch': File exists "  this is the complete error message.

Comment: if the file is not present then there may a prob in creating hard link. but it shows File exists.

Comment: You may use the `--skip-old-files` option, this makes leave untouched the existing files and will not treat is as an error.

Comment: it shows "unrecognised option '--skip-old-files' "